# Mail sends from localhost but not from live site on digital ocean

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, sendgrid

I am using the Sendgrid API to send emails from my Node.js project. When running on my local machine this works just fine but now I have deployed to Digital Ocean (Ubuntu) the mails do not send. I have read that Digital Ocean blocks smtp ports by default and you can apparently open them through the command line but I can't find an easy to understand explanation on how to do this.

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const sendgridTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sendgridTransport({
      auth: {
          api_key: process.env.SENDGRID_API
      }
    }));

    return transporter.sendMail({
      to: 'info@example.com',
      from: email,
      subject: subject,
      html: `<h1>Contact Form</h1>
            <p>Name: ${name}</p>
            <p>Email: ${email}</p>
            <p>${comments}</p>
    `
    });
```

*UPDATE*

If I remove the .env for the api key and actually hardcode it in eg:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sendgridTransport({
  auth: {
      api_key: '12345677788999'
  }
}));
```

then my emails send. This is my .env file ( I am using dotenv)

```
DB_USER=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_NAME=mydbname
SENDGRID_API=12345677788999
```

So, not sure why that would be?

Comment: Can you provide us with some code? Much easier to check the problem that way

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Can you make sure that `process.env.SENDGRID_API` is correctly configured on your remote server (Digital Ocean)?

Comment: @molamk, not sure what you mean? That is just the API key

Comment: sure, but I'm thinking maybe on your server, the app can't find that environment variable. Configuring the environment for remote servers can be tricky. Just call `console.log(process.env.SENDGRID_API)` to check if it's really there (on the Digital Ocean) server

Comment: @molamk, so I just found something interesting. I am going to update my question so it's easier to see the code. Please check it in a minute.

Comment: @molamk, I am trying to console.log it but not sure where to see it. On local machine I can see stuff logged to console through my visual studio terminal. I have used ssh to connect but see nothing there

Comment: there are a lot of options here and not enough details to go through them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you exported this "SENDGRID_API" in the environment. Then only you can use process.env.SomeEnvironmentVar.

If you are using PM2. You will have to add it to the ecosystem file. Then it will use that config and boot your application. Making all the vars available.

Comment: not sure what you mean in your first sentence. I am also using .env to connect to my mongo db and that is working all fine. Send grid works fine when I hardcode the api key in instead of using .env. How do you export it into the environemnt? Yes, I am using PM2.

Comment: you can use export  SENDGRID_API="your api key" and then start the server.

Comment: Do I type that into the ssh terminal or where?

Comment: Yes in the terminal. And you can echo $exported_var to check.

Comment: Just realized that I was doing something stupid. Didn't have the env variables  setup on the live server, only localhost. No wonder.  But now the site doesn't work at all, getting a 502 bad gateway error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using SendGrid, Digitalocean (Ubuntu) and PM2.

It seems that PM2 doesn't automatically detect changes in .env file as @himank mentioned in his answer, so i had to delete the project from PM2, then started it again.

Kindly note:

- I followed this guide to set global Environment variables:
  https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-linux/
- I also followed this guide to configure PM2 with my Nodejs (Nestjs) project:
  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-20-04